# How to update image in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I created image upload which works fine but I also want it to be updated. When I add a need image it updates correctly but I if don't want to change the image and leave it as it is, then my current image can't be retrieve.i want to update my factory_name(field name) only sometimes. when i update image it updated successfully,but when i update factory_name only the existing image is missing. Please help me how to do this?

this my view file

```
            <form action="<?php echo base_url('login/insert_factory/'.$id); ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <?php
           $id =$this->uri->segment(3);
           if($id == "")
            {
            ?>  
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label" for="field-1">Factory Name</label>
                <!--span class="desc">e.g. "Beautiful Mind"</span-->
                <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="factory_name" class="form-control" >
                </div>
            </div>
             <?php

                }
                else
               { ?> 
           <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label" for="field-1">Factory Name</label>
                <!--span class="desc">e.g. "Beautiful Mind"</span-->
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="factory_name" value="<?php echo $result->factory_name; ?>" class="form-control" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

           <?php
                            if($id == "")
                            {
                            ?>  

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label" for="field-1">Upload Logo</label>
                <!--span class="desc">e.g. "Beautiful Mind"</span-->
                <div class="controls">
                     <input type="file"  name="upload_logo" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php

                }
                else
               { ?> 
           <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label" for="field-1">Upload Logo</label>
                <!--span class="desc">e.g. "Beautiful Mind"</span-->
                <div class="controls">
                     <input type="file"  name="upload_logo" value="<?php echo $result->factory_logo; ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
           <?php } ?>
           <?php
                            if($id == "")
                            {
                            ?>  
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" />        

                </div>
            </div>
            <?php

                }
                else
               { ?> 
           <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update"  />        

                </div>
            </div>
             <?php } ?>
            </form>
```

this my controller code:

```
 public function insert_factory()
     { 
        $id =$this->uri->segment(3);

        if($id == "")
        {
        if(isset($_FILES['upload_logo'])){

              $errors= array();
              $file_name = $_FILES['upload_logo']['name'];
              $file_tmp =$_FILES['upload_logo']['tmp_name'];

              if(empty($errors)==true){
                 move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"assets/uploads/".$file_name);

                // echo "Success";
              }else{
                 print_r($errors);
              }

                $fields = array(
                   'factory_name' => $this->input->post('factory_name',True),
                   'factory_logo' => $file_name
                );

                $result = $this->login_model->insert_factory($fields);

                if($result){
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg',' Factory Created Successfully!');
                    redirect('login/view_factory');
                }else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg','Factory Cannot Created.!');
                    redirect('login/create_factory');
                }
            } 
        }else{

            if(isset($_FILES['upload_logo'])){

              $errors= array();
              $file_name = $_FILES['upload_logo']['name'];
              $file_tmp =$_FILES['upload_logo']['tmp_name'];

              if(empty($errors)==true){
                 move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"assets/uploads/".$file_name);

                // echo "Success";
              }else{
                 print_r($errors);
              }

                $fields = array(
                   'factory_name' => $this->input->post('factory_name',True),
                   'factory_logo' => $file_name
                );

                $this->db->where('factory_id', $id);
                $this->db->update('create_factory', $fields);
                if($this->db->affected_rows()>0)
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg',' Factory Updated Successfully!');
                }else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg','Factory Cannot Updated.!');
                    redirect('login/create_factory');
                }
                redirect(base_url('login/view_factory'));
        } 

        }
     }
```

And this my model file:

```
    public function insert_factory($fields)
        {
            $this->db->insert('create_factory',$fields);
            return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, in both if and else blocks, please modify your existing code in order to not update empty image when image is not provided and only factory name is provided.

This code in both if and else blocks:

```
$fields = array(
    'factory_name' => $this->input->post('factory_name',True),
    'factory_logo' => $file_name
);
```

Needs to be change to:

```
$fields['factory_name'] = $this->input->post('factory_name', True);

if (!empty($file_name)) {
    $fields['factory_logo'] = $file_name;
}
```

Comment: ya i replaced but syntax error occurs Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in D:\xampp\htdocs\MTBF\application\controllers\Login.php on line 99

Comment: My mistake, forgot semicolon at the end of $fields['factory_name'] = $this->input->post('factory_name',True)

Just updated my answer!